# How to find second and third largest using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT name, count(*) as num FROM `tracker` group by sender order by num desc
```

I want to find out the second largest and third largest value of count(*).

***Table***

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
ABC
ABC
XYZ
```

By using query I m getting

```
ABC 3
XYZ 2
PQR 1
```

I want to display **XYZ 2** separately and **PQR 1**

I m using mysql.

Comment: [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is your friend.

Comment: how to use **LIMIT**  in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `LIMIT 1, 2` to the end of your current query should do what you want.

In this form of LIMIT, the first number is the offset/index into the results to begin at, and the second is the maximum number of results (as normal). For the question's example, the returned results should be:

```
XYZ 2
PQR 1
```

If you wanted to retrieve the second and third through separately executed queries, the syntax would be `LIMIT 1, 1` and `LIMIT 2, 1` respectively.

Comment: If you can add the reason for the structure, explain the syntax to the OP (and everyone else) then I think this should be the right answer.

Comment: I want to display XYZ 2 separately and PQR 1

Comment: @PrabhatKashyap can you define what you mean by "separately", the solution presented here displays the 2nd and 3rd row of the *current* SQL query, so each row is a separate entity.

Comment: @Martin Separately means in two different query 1st for 2nd largest and other for third largest

Comment: @PrabhatKashyap I just edited, see the final sentence for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is one more way to do it. Certainly not the most elegant.

```
select t.name, count(*) as cnt
from t 
group by name
having count(*) <
(select max(num) as mxn from 
 (
   SELECT name, count(*) as num
    FROM t group by name
  ) a
 )
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e09b5f/1